# Packaging a customized Material UI ThemeProvider Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themeprovider

I'm creating a Material UI theme for my company using Material UI's createMuiTheme API and their ThemeProvider component.  The theme works as expected when I wrap native Material UI components within it.  What I'm trying to do though is create a separate library of composite Material UI components that other developers in my company can include as dependencies in their projects and then wrap their root applications in the MUI ThemeProvider component.  One common library of reusable components, and one common theme, each stored and maintained separately.  In practice, the theme works as expected on native Material UI components but has no effect on composite components built with Material UI and packaged with webpack.

```
import React from 'react';
import {MyCompositeComponent} from '@my-mui-composite-components'
import themeSettings from './company-theme-settings';
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const Root = (props) => {
  const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
    seed: 'my-app',
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeSettings}>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <MyCompositeComponent/>
      </StylesProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

When the root app above loads, the theme settings aren't applied to .  Is what I'm trying to do here possible?  Is there a 'right' way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

When I was first confronted with this problem, I assumed that I could solve it by externalizing @material-ui/core as a peer dependency in my library.  When I first tried this and attempted to import my library as a dependency, webpack threw an error indicating that @material-ui/core was not found in my library's node_modules folder.  So, I started questioning what I thought I knew about how peer dependencies worked and started looking for alternate solutions.  As it turns out, the peer dependency path is the correct one.  The issue is rooted in the fact that I'm running both my app and my library locally.  I just needed to include an alias for @material-ui/core in my application's webpack.config file as shown here:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@material-ui/core': path.resolve('node_modules', '@material-ui/core'),
  },
},
```

See this [link](https://medium.com/@penx/managing-dependencies-in-a-node-package-so-that-they-are-compatible-with-npm-link-61befa5aaca7) for further info.